# French guillemets specific look

Tags: punctuation, csquotes

I want to find the french guillemets in latex. To be honest I found them by many ways:

```
\og text \fg{}
```

with or without OT1 and french babel, but they do not produce the same result as those which can be seen here: [www.phys.ens.fr/~dalibard/Notes_de_cours/X_MQ_2003.pdf](http://www.phys.ens.fr/~dalibard/Notes_de_cours/X_MQ_2003.pdf) on page 7

What do I have to typeset to get these ones?

Comment: Hum, the guillemets shown in this article are not the standard ones at all. Look at Pluton's answer for the correct version.

Comment: Yes, please refer to the answer provided by Pluton. I had the same questions as you a few weeks ago when I began to write my internship report. Only `csquotes` package does provide the right characters for French, and is way easier when you need to write multiple language documents (typically a report for your programming courses, like I had to).

Answer (score 8):

The characters you're mentioning show that the document is using the obsolete package `aeguill`. If you really want to get that shape, you can load the necessary fonts and change the definition of `\guillemotleft` and `\guillemotright` to use `wncyr`; but be aware of the fact that you're using guillemets in Cyrillic style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\frenchbsetup{og = «, fg = »}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{wncyr}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wncyr}{m}{n}{<->wncyr10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wncyr}{m}{it}{<->wncyi10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wncyr}{m}{sc}{<->wncysc10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wncyr}{b}{n}{<->wncyb10}{}

\DeclareTextCommand{\guillemotleft}{T1}{%
  {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{wncyr}\selectfont\symbol{"3C}}%
}
\DeclareTextCommand{\guillemotright}{T1}{%
  {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{wncyr}\selectfont\symbol{"3E}}%
}

\begin{document}

pourrait \og exister \fg{} se trouve

pourrait « exister » se trouve

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare the output when the “normal” guillemets are used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\frenchbsetup{og = «, fg = »}

\begin{document}

pourrait \og exister \fg{} se trouve

pourrait « exister » se trouve

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that you do not even need to load the `aeguill` package to get that sort of cyrillic guillemets. It is enough to load the`babel` package with option `french` while keeping the OT1 encoding. Cf. my answer below.

Comment: And with Frenchb (the `french` option of `babel`), you can also insert typographical guillemets in your PDF by using the guillemets characters of the keyboard: you only need to insert the following command in the preamble: `\frenchbsetup{og = «, fg = »}`. Then they will behave as the `\og` and `\fg` commands, i.e inserting the typographical guillemets and the adequate hard spaces (smaller than `~`, bigger than `\,`).

Comment: @fpast Thanks for the reminder about `\frenchbsetup`. However, if I leave OT1 as default encoding, I get guillemets emulated with `<` signs.

Comment: Indeed, but it works as expected. My bad, I should have wrote: ‘‘Then they will behave as the `\og` and `\fg` commands, i.e inserting the guillemets (french or cyrillic, following the context) and the adequate hard spaces (smaller than `~`, bigger than `\,`).’’

Answer (score 3):

This is (alas) the kind of guillemets you obtain with the french option of babel, when you forget/neglect to use the T1 font encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
\og essai \fg.
\end{document}
```

[image]

They are the same as in the article, but they are not the standard ones. One should also insert `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble to obtain the correct french guillemets.

Answer (score 2):

These can be obtained with the`aeguill` package and option `[cyr]`,  which uses the french quotes from `wncyr`. The problem is `aeguill` supposes you load the obsolete `ae` package, but maybe it is possible to adapt part of the code so as to use these quotes with, say, Latin Modern.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution below. Note that the package `csquotes` is used to create a new command `\emphg` (emphasize with guillemets). Some people here will say that this is not appropriate since `csquotes` was created to handle quotings but it does a nice work.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\newcommand\emphg[1]{\enquote{#1}}
\begin{document}
La mécanique quantique a d'inattendu que l'on n'arrive pas jusqu'à présent à la mettre en défaut. La seule indication qu'une \emphg{nouvelle} forme de physique pourrait \og exister \fg{} se trouve dans la cosmologie, et concerne les $10^{-43}$ premières secondes de \emphg{l'univers}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just realized that I am most probably not answering the question.