# \textls letterspacing and parbox

Tags: letterspacing, parbox

I have a hack for fitting as much text as possible in a 2-line parbox using \textls (microtype package). Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[french=guillemets]{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{qag}\fontsize{6pt}{6.6pt}\selectfont

\newlength{\mytextheight}
\newcount\foo

\def\mytext{CA«S»TILLA 2000, vert foncé et or (millésime 1995)}

\foo=0
\loop
\settoheight{\mytextheight}{\parbox{70pt}{\textls[\foo]{\mytext}}}
\advance \foo -5
\ifdim \mytextheight>10pt
\repeat

\parbox{70pt}{\mytext}      

\vspace{4mm}

\parbox{70pt}{\textls[\foo]{\mytext}}

\end{document}
```

For some reason the space before the closing guillemet is different from the one after the opening guillemet, which looks ugly. How may I correct this? Thanks for any idea.
[image]

Comment: don't put `%` after literal integers.

Comment: I get `! Package csquotes Error: Invalid argument.` from your example file

Comment: compiles just fine here

Comment: removed all `%`

Comment: I see what it is you have used `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` specifying the file is in the legacy 8bit encoding but as posted to this site it (like every post here) is in UTF-8 so you need to remove the inputenc line

Comment: Remove `aeguill` as soon as possible.

Comment: It seems `aeguill` is indeed the culprit here, thanks. Is there a replacement to get "good-looking" guillemets as in `aeguill`?

Comment: I used the solution mentioned here ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233546/french-guillemets-specific-look)) to replace `aeguill` ... and the problem is back!

Comment: If you remove `aeguill`, you get the guillemets provided by TeX Gyre Adventor. Why would you take them from another font?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is as follows:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{wncyr}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wncyr}{m}{n}{<->wncyr10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wncyr}{m}{it}{<->wncyi10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wncyr}{m}{sc}{<->wncysc10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wncyr}{b}{n}{<->wncyb10}{}

\DeclareTextCommand{\guillemotleft}{T1}{%
  {\hbox{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{wncyr}\selectfont\symbol{"3C}}}%
}
\DeclareTextCommand{\guillemotright}{T1}{%
  {\hbox{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{wncyr}\selectfont\symbol{"3E}}}%
}
```

It replaces `aeguill` and the hboxes avoid the weird-looking space before the closing guillemet.
[image]