# French guillemets in English document

Tags: overleaf, french

Is there a way to get French guillemets (like here: [French guillemets specific look](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233546/french-guillemets-specific-look)) without changing the language to French?

I would like to use them in an English document.

Comment: you can use the csquotes package to setup quote styles.

Comment: It might also depent on whether you also need the extra spacing, If not you can also use » and « directly from the keyboard.

Comment: Easy to do, if you are compiling with lualatex, using the fontspec package. It understands utf-8 encoding, so you can simply paste the characters from a utf-8 character map. If you need extra spacing, code `\,` provides a narrow space. Note: If your only use of French is in dialogue between English and French speakers, standard style is to use the same punctuation for both languages. In other words, both speakers use English curly quotes, or (if the other way around) both use guillemets.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the T1 font encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\guilsinglleft single guillemets\guilsinglright

<<double guillemets>>

‹single guillemets›

«double guillemets»

\end{document}
```

[image]

The direct input might be preferable, if you can obtain the characters from your keyboard.